# Xcode list of simulator devices is missing for some apps, there for others

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

[image: Simulator selection list]

This box shows the app name and where it will run.  For ONLY some of my apps, it has suddenly disappeared.  The simulator still works for the last setting.

On top of that, perhaps related, everything (except search) on the Xcode Help pull down menu goes to Documentation-Adding an iOS App Icon Set or Launch Image Set.  Just to be clear, clicking on What's New, or Release Notes, or Xcode Overview, all go to that same document.

I have rebooted my MacBook.  No help.  I updated to El Capitan three or four days ago, but this problem just started a few minutes ago.

Comment: Create newSchema then u can find. If not check with device.

Answer (score 0):

It'll only show the targets for the project you currently have open. If you want to run your other apps just open the `xcodeproj` file (or the `xcodeworkspace` if you're using CocoaPods)

Comment: I think you missed the question.  For some projects that are open it's there. Close that project and open another, it's gone.  I'm a long time user of Xcode, and this is a new one for me.  These projects have been tested hundreds of times, but the box is gone, for some.

Comment: Sorry, which version of Xcode are you using? I noticed some weird Xcode behavior with Xcode 6.x after I upgraded to El Capitan. It was resolved after I upgraded to Xcode 7

Comment: I'll check that out.  I can't even discover which version because the help menus are not working.

Comment: That's weird man, if I were you i would just delete Xcode and install 7.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line, it was Xcode 6 trying to run with El Capitan.  I loaded 7 and everything got better instantly.  Thanks for all the comments.